# Rails image_tag not working with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile with a Rails app and have various profile images uploaded via the Carrierwave gem. When I use the rails `image_tag` with the user object there is no output in the HTML. When I inspect the element it just shows an empty `<div>`.

However when I use the same `image_tag` with my App version which does not use jQuery Mobile the image is displayed. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

For the particular list view I am making, the documentation recommends the following format:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li> <a href="#">
            <img src="../_assets/img/example.jpg">
        <h2> Example </h2>
    <li>
 <ul>
```

I have tried:

```
<li>
       <img src="/uploads/user/photo" >
</li>
```

and

```
link_to (...) do 
    <li>
             <%= image_tag (object.image_url) %>
    <li/>

<% end %>
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the image_tag in a link_to tag as follows:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.thumbimage.url), :class=>"read" ,:remote=> true  %>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    <%= link_to 'edit post', edit_post_path(post), "data-icon" => "gear" %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
```

In this case an image from the database is displayed by using the paper clip gem. Have a look at the gem in this link please :

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

This is how the html mark up looks in the DOC

```
<li class="ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child">
    <a href="/jqmoblog/posts?class=read&amp;remote=true" class="ui-btn"><img alt="Missing" src="/jqmoblog/images/missing.png?1391029935"></a>
    <a href="/jqmoblog/posts/1" class="">First Post!</a>
    <a href="/jqmoblog/posts/1/edit" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-gear" title="edit post"></a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that - it only seems to work if the `link_to` is outside the `<li>` tags but the actual image still doesn't appear. The documentation says the image link should be the first child element in the list. When looking at the Jquery example: (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html) and inspecting the element it shows as: `<div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="index.html" class="ui-link-inherit"> 
    <img src="images/album-af.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">
    <h3 class="ui-li-heading">The Suburbs</h3>
    <p class="ui-li-desc">Arcade Fire</p>
   </a></div>`